# Algorithm always provide a $2$_$sum$ with at least ONE prime? In polynomial-time?

Tags: algorithms, primes

Function Problem: Given $N$ find a $2$_$sum$ that uses at least $ONE$ prime.

**Fact:** Prime Gaps grow logarithmically on average. And, in worst case if memory serves correct it grows with a bounded constant.

- Take notice that $count$ (defined below) will only equal to $s$, if the $AKS$ primality statement executes $s$ times. This will find our $s$-amount primes to generate a $2$_$sum$ by finding the difference of $N$-$P$.

### Algorithm

$N$ = $13$

$s$ = $binary~length~of~N$

$p$ = 0

$count$ = $0$

$primes$ = []

$WHILE$ $count$ $<$ $s$:

$~~~~~~~~~$ $p$=$p$+$1$

$~~~~~~~~~$ $IF$ $AKS$-$PRIMALITY$($p$) == $TRUE$:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ $primes$.append($p$)

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ $count$ = $count$ + 1

$OUTPUT$ FOUND $2$_$SUM$, $(N-P)$ + $P$

$OUTPUT$ VERIFY SOLUTION $(N-P)$+$P$ == $N$

```
Found 2-sum:  6 + 7
Verify Solution:  True
```

I'm an amateur who made computer-science a hobby, and I'm not sure what would the exact time complexity would be.

### Question

What would be the best estimate of the time complexity?

Would it fail if $P$ $>$ $N$? (an easy fix)

Comment: I can improve space complexity by getting rid of the appending and just using $primes$ = $p$ instead! I noticed a speedup in python by doing this!

Comment: What does the output have to do with $N$? What is a 2_Sum? What's wrong with $P=2$?

Comment: @YonatanN That would be boring if we use fixed primes. And, I should've said that that a 2_sum is two integers added together that equals $N$.